# Equalize a set of images' histograms to their mean

Tags: image-processing

I have a set of 1000+ grayscale SEM micrographs I am trying to binarize, but the differential brightness/contrast makes it difficult to binarize using all of the binarization and segmentation methods available on mathematica.  Therefore I need to preprocess them first to equalize the histograms.

I want to take the mean histogram of the entire set to create a reference probability distribution (PDF).
Then I want to use HistogramTransform to equalize each image to the reference PDF.

I am able to get mean levels for each bin using ImageLevels, but I am not able to convert this back into a plot of the mean histogram from which to apply HistogramDistribution to get the reference probability distribution.

Any advice on how to get a mean histogram?

Comment: You should post your code of progress so far. Also see `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` and `BrightnessEqualize`.

Comment: I will shortly, however those two functions are adaptive within images, not across images.